# R: Small Data Frame 10 Mb Throws Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.4 Gb

Tags: r, memory-management, memory-leaks, knitr

I'm working with a data frame approximately 50K rows by 20 columns. It's about 10 MB in size as a tab delimited text file. I run some moderate analysis on it utilizing R scripts (.R) and everything is working fine. I started writing the report in *R Markdown* to package everything in a nice neat document.

When I run the `rmarkdown::render("my_document.Rmd")` command a nice HTML is rendered. Occasionally in *Windows10* I get this `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.4 Gb`, or X Gb. If I push <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow on my keyboard, and run the command immediately again everything works fine and life goes on. I don't know why the error is intermittent, but at least things work again on the next try of the same command. I also find it hard to believe an object of size 15.4 Gb is generated from my original 10 MB file, which I only run basic commands on such as `dplyr::filter()` or `dplyr::group_by() %>% summarise(n()) >%> etc.`, I don't add rows or columns to the original data frame.

If I do this same procedure in Ubuntu Linux I never get the error, and my session totally freezes instead. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't even work and I'm forced to hard reset. That's more of a headache as it happens about once or twice an hour. I've left the System Monitor open and noticed the *rsession* consumed memory goes from 200 MB to 7 GB (basically all of my 8 Gb of RAM) when this situation occurs.

What road do I go down? Is this an R issue? R Studio? Rmarkdown package? knitR package? Pandoc issue? I just updated R (3.4.3), R Studio (1.1.423), all my R packages, and the issue is still occurring. I don't really expect an answer, but am hoping for guidance on where to even start. I'd take a band-aid fix if the root cause determination is unlikely. Seems it may be.

**[EDIT] I've added a redacted version of my .Rmd file. But it basically includes everything, and *yes* my actual .Rmd file is not much longer than what's seen below. I'll also paste the error message if that helps. You'll notice I've added white space several times, that's why you see the `div style` arguments.**

````
---
title: "February Reporting"
date: "Dept XYZ [February 20, 2018]"
output: html_document
---

<div style="margin-bottom:35px;">
</div>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Introduction

This report meets the requirements of *XYZ123, Body of Standards* at `Revision: 12` `Version: G`. In particular we are concerned with:

* ***2.5 Report Out***
    + *2.5.1* On a periodic basis...
        - *2.5.1.1* The weekly output...
        - *2.5.1.2* The weekly output...
        - *2.5.1.3* The weekly output...
    + *2.5.2* On a periodic basis...
        - *2.5.2.1* The annual output...
        - *2.5.2.2* The annual output...
        - *2.5.2.3* The annual output...
    + *2.5.3* However, etc.
etc.

<div style="margin-bottom:35px;">
</div>

# Data Sources - \[Verified with XYZ]
***
A basic analysis is performed but is not indicative of...
The analysis often utilizes the following variable, represented by:
$$ \text{The Eqation is} = \frac{\text{Multi word variable}}{\text{multi word variable}} $$
````

That's about it for my R Markdown file. And the error is here:

> rmarkdown::render("mark_output.Rmd")
>
> processing file: mark_output.Rmd   |.........
>   |  14%   ordinary text without R code
>
> |...................                                              | 
>   29% label: setup (with options)  List of 1  $ include: logi FALSE
>
> |............................                                     | 
>   43%   ordinary text without R code
>
> |.....................................                            | 
>   57% label: cars   |..............................................
>   |  71%   ordinary text without R code
>
> |........................................................         | 
>   86% label: pressure (with options)  List of 3  $ fig.height: num 7  $
>   fig.width : language 12 + (4/9)  $ echo      : logi FALSE
>
> |.................................................................|
>   100%   ordinary text without R code
>
> output file: mark_output.knit.md
>
> "C:/Users/stackinator/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   mark_output.utf8.md --to html --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart
>   --output mark_output.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\stackinator\Documents\Rlibs\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html"
>   --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\stackinator\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGi2lRl\rmarkdown-str460774e669e.html"
>   --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
>
> Output created: mark_output.html Error: cannot allocate vector of size
>   15.4 Gb

Comment: Can you show the minimum Rmd-code, which shows the error?

Comment: Unless you provide a reproducible example, there isn't much anything can do.

Comment: minimum Rmd-code *now* included, along with the error message.

Comment: If you run `gc()` before doing the above does it solve it?

Comment: The R code is what we need to see. Cant say anything with just the rmarkdown document...

Comment: I noticed I can run any moderate analysis that gets my `rsession` up to ~200 MB. Then I run `rmarkdown::render("my_document.Rmd")` maybe 15-20 times, consecutively, and the system will freeze. And I've also tried `gc(); rmarkdown::render("my_document.Rmd")` and unfortunately that doesn't help.

Comment: I am also having this error. Watching this question...

Answer (score 1):

Head on over and check out this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887792/rmarkdownrender-in-a-loop-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size)

In a nutshell the post explains that in a loop situation,

> Adding `knitr::knit_meta(class=NULL, clean = TRUE)` before
>   `rmarkdown::render(input=file, etc)` seems to do the trick.