# rmarkdown::render() in a loop - cannot allocate vector of size

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a bunch of directories with Rmd files to be compiled into HTML. Each call to `rmarkdown::render` includes a large list of `params`. Everything works fine when I render the Rmd files individually.

However, when I execute a function that loops over the directories and builds the HTML files it crashes after it has completed nine (it is not a specific Rmd causing the problem, it crashes on the 9th regardless of the order).

The relevant part of the error traceback is:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 38.4 Gb

8. knitr::knit_meta_add(old_knit_meta, attr(old_knit_meta, "knit_meta_id")) 

7. rmarkdown::render(input = RMDfile, output_file = RMDfileout, 
        output_format = output, output_dir = dir, param = params, 
        quiet = quiet)
```

The problem appears to be caused by this line in `rmarkdown::render`:

```
 on.exit({
    knit_meta_reset()
    if (length(old_knit_meta)) {
      knitr::knit_meta_add(old_knit_meta, attr(old_knit_meta, 
                                               "knit_meta_id"))
    }
  }, add = TRUE)
```

It appears to me that the `params` from the previous calls are being saved in the meta-data, and is getting too large after `rmarkdown::render` is called 9 times in the function.

`rmarkdown::knitr` has a `knit_meta` argument, but the help documentation says 
"*(For expert use) Meta data generated by knitr*" and I'm no `knitr` expert.

The Rmd files are completely independent from each other. Is there a way to reset the knitr meta-data for each call to `rmarkdown::render`?

I'm hoping someone can offer a quick fix or workaround for this. If not, I'll develop an example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share the code which is used to create the loop over the files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After digging around in `rmarkdown::render` code for a while I've found a solution.

Adding `knitr::knit_meta(class=NULL, clean = TRUE)` before `rmarkdown::render(input=file, etc)` seems to do the trick..

Comment: Beautiful. I added some lines to remove any unnecessary data between loop iterations; that didn't work. I would have to clear the workspace every 8 reports and try again. This solution worked for me (all 20 reports can be rendered at once). THANK YOU!