# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1033 Execution halted

Tags: html, r, knitr, pandoc

I am getting below error message while knitting my rmd file to html. Can you please help me with this?

> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   linearRegression-1-.utf8.md --to html4 --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart
>   --output linearRegression-1-.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\anjal\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html"
>   --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\anjal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSiwyJO\rmarkdown-str12247b161a33.html"
>   --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
>   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1033 Execution
>   halted

Regards,
Anjali

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandoc error 1033 when rendering multiple Rmarkdown reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994237/pandoc-error-1033-when-rendering-multiple-rmarkdown-reports)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The error happened to me when I install tynitex. So I uninstall it with `tynitex::uninstall_tynitex()`. After that delete the Html, log and tex generated by Rmarkdown. After that build your Html and should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was because I had a lot of accents as part of mi text chuncks (`á`, `é`, `ñ`...). Sometimes these were converted to their ASCII codes (`Ã¡`, `Ã©`, `Ãº`) when the code was saved, and made the job failed when I knitted.
I replaced the special characters for their non-accent versions (`a`, `e`, `n`). Was not the final solution for me, but it's a good workaround, the "pandoc document conversion failed with error 1033" went away, and the notebook knitted successfully

Answer (score 0):

In my Case, the error because the project name contains Chinese. The previous name of my project is **GAM_广义加性模型**. After I change it to **GAM** and at the same time change the R project file to **GAM.Rproj**, it works!
So I think maybe you can check whether there are non-English characters in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

My code had a "\n" in it. It is a new line symbol for java and it works on R. But fails to knit until it is deleted.